# Webservice Add/Update Combinations Prestashop

Tags: web-services, combinations, prestashop

I read, i try, i looking informations about how add / update combinations by webservice, in presta 1.5.3 but still i don't know how to do that.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `I read, i try` - great, could you show us [`what you have tried`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? This way we might be able to see what's wrong with your code and suggest you ways to fix and improve it.

Comment: I found this link http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/198631-two-bugs-15117-and-1520-in-webservice-product-creation-and-update/ but without combinations. I think now, that, i use add product, i set disable product, and next when i update the product, i set combinations. But i don't know how. I was try with $resources -> associations -> combinations, but all what i write, was wrong. I must say that i don't like xml, always i have problem with that. This is my worst thing. 
I want add, and update. But i didn't find even example with edit combinations.

Comment: the problem is for me to add 2 values in the product_option_values node... anyone has solved?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning combinations to products via Webservice is a multi-step operation (unlike CSV import).

- given a product with id_product
- add product_options (BO *Attribute Names*)
- add product_option_values (BO *Attribute Values*) to product_options
- add combinations while specifying id_product

Start by initialising PrestaShopWebservice with DEBUG=true:

```
$api = new PrestaShopWebservice($psShopUrl, $psAuthKey, $psDebug);
```

Instead of building the XML from scratch get a template for the resource you need like this:

```
$sxml = $api->get(array('url' => $psShopUrl.'api/'.$resource.'?schema=blank'));
```

The response is a SimpleXMLElement which is a easier to manipulate than DOM.

**NB:** The response contains all wrapper nodes and you must send the same back in your request i.e. PSWebServiceLibrary will **not** recreate them for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<combination>
...
</combination>
</prestashop>
```

SXML manipulation example:

```
$schema = $api->get(array('url' => $psShopUrl.'api/product_options?schema=blank'));
$data = $schema->children()->children();
$data->is_color_group = false;
$data->group_type = $group_type;   // radio, select
$data->name->language[0] = 'attribute private name';
$data->public_name->language[0] = 'attribute public name';
$xml = $schema->asXML();    // all of it!
$ret = $api->add(array('resource' => 'product_options', 'postXml' => $xml));
$id_attribute_group = (int)$ret->children()->children()->id;    // save for next step
```

Then get `product_option_values` schema, set data and the `id_attribute_group` from previous step. And so on.

Updating is the same except you will `get` the resource by *id* and then `edit`:

```
$sxml = $api->get(array('resource' => $resource, 'id' => $id));
...
$ret = $api->edit(array('resource' => $resource, 'id' => $id, 'putXml' => $xml));
```

As for adding multiple *id* values to the `product_option_values` node in the `combinations` resource you can use the array_push shortcut `[]`:

```
$data->associations->product_option_values->product_option_values[]->id = 123;
$data->associations->product_option_values->product_option_values[]->id = 456;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work fine for me :

```
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, $api_key, FALSE);
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => $url .'/api/combinations?schema=blank'));

$resources = $xml->children()->children();

$resources->id_product          = $ps_product_id;
$resources->wholesale_price     = $wholesale_price;
$resources->price               = $price;
$resources->unit_price_impact   = $unit_price_impact;
$resources->minimal_quantity    = $minimal_quantity;
$resources->quantity            = $quantity;
$resources->weight              = $weight;

$resources->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value[0]->id = $color_id;
$resources->associations->product_option_values->product_option_value[1]->id = $size_id;

$request = $xml->asXML();

//This is a function that curl request to specific URL using method (POST)
$response = ps_curl($url . '/api/combinations', $request, 'POST', $api_key);

$xml_load  = simplexml_load_string($response);
$id        = $xml_load->combination->id;
```

I hope that's helpful :)

Comment: Hi. When I try your example, and fiddle with my own apikey, url, etc. It sais bad response. Any idear why? Do I have to enable other things except the webservice and restrictions? =)